# ActiveRecord associations returns empty results when using includes or preload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Some associations are returning empty results when using includes or preload, works fine otherwise.

**Problem - Association returns empty results**

```
2.5.5 :099 > Domain.where(id: 1).includes(:current_user_roles).first.current_user_roles
  Domain Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "public"."domains".* FROM "public"."domains" WHERE "public"."domains"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "public"."domains"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Query Trace:
      bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
  SQL (2.7ms)  SELECT "roles"."id" AS t0_r0, "roles"."name" AS t0_r1, "roles"."resource_type" AS t0_r2, "roles"."resource_id" AS t0_r3, "roles"."created_at" AS t0_r4, "roles"."updated_at" AS t0_r5, "users_roles"."user_id" AS t1_r0, "users_roles"."role_id" AS t1_r1 FROM "roles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users_roles" ON "users_roles"."role_id" = "roles"."id" WHERE "roles"."resource_type" = $1 AND "users_roles"."user_id" = $2 AND "roles"."resource_id" = $3  [["resource_type", "Domain"], ["user_id", 1], ["resource_id", 1]]
Query Trace:
      bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

It works when not using includes/preload

```
2.5.5 :100 > Domain.where(id: 1).first.current_user_roles
  Domain Load (2.4ms)  SELECT  "public"."domains".* FROM "public"."domains" WHERE "public"."domains"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "public"."domains"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Query Trace:
      bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
  Role Load (2.9ms)  SELECT  "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" INNER JOIN "roles" "roles_current_user_roles" ON "users_roles"."role_id" = "roles_current_user_roles"."id" WHERE "roles_current_user_roles"."resource_id" = $1 AND "roles_current_user_roles"."resource_type" = $2 AND "users_roles"."user_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["resource_id", 1], ["resource_type", "Domain"], ["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
Query Trace:
      bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Role id: 1248, name: "admin", resource_type: "Domain", resource_id: 1, created_at: "2021-05-01 13:31:19", updated_at: "2021-05-01 13:31:19">]>
```

**Setup (Simplified)**

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: :users_roles

  belongs_to :resource,
             polymorphic: true

  has_many :users_roles
end

class UsersRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify
end

class Domain < ApplicationRecord
  resourcify

  has_many :current_user_users_roles, -> { where(user_id: current_user.id) }, class_name: 'UsersRole', through: :roles, source: :users_roles
  
  has_many :current_user_roles, class_name: 'Role', through: :current_user_users_roles, source: :role
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your associations are way off. Rolify uses a `has_and_belongs_to_many` (HABTM) association which is headless to join users and roles. If you were to replicate the basic Rolify setup it would look like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles 
end

class Role
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users 
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true
end
```

Note that since `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations are headless there is no `UserRoles` model. And in your case that model will actually never be loaded or used. See the guides for an in depth explaination of [has_many through: vs HABTM](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many). Your Role model should look like this:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :resource,
             polymorphic: true
             optional: true
  validates :resource_type,
             inclusion: { in: Rolify.resource_types },
             allow_nil: true
  scopify
end
```

Support for using `has_many through:` with Rolify [was originally slated for Rolify 3.0](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/pull/227) but has never happened. I [came up with a workaroud in 2017](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/issues/318) which however doesn't seem to work with current versions of rails. If you really want use Rolify (which you're basically just clobbering) to scope a resource you would do it with:

```
class Domain < ApplicationRecord
  resourcify
end

domains = Domain.with_role(nil, current_user)
```

Comment: while I tend to agree OP's associations/models look funky I'm wondering if his funkiness somehow uncovered a Rails bug or you simply can't/shouldn't include associations like that

Comment: @JoelBlum maybe. The only real difference I can spot between the two queries is that the query with includes is just selecting `SELECT "roles"."id" ` and the other is selecting `"roles".*`. I'm also confused as hell as to why `where(user_id: current_user.id)` is not generating a nomethod error - what can of black magic is this?

Comment: Yes I was thrown off by that as well, I have no answer. Guides says you are passed the owner object (in his case instance of Domain, and in any case nothing with kwargs), how is this not exploding.

Comment: @JoelBlum when you define a association with a lambda its evaluated at class level so you are not passed an instance of the class. I guess you could access current_user if you made the instance variable from your controller a global and then defined a getter in your ApplicationRecord class. Anybody doing so should be tarred and feathed though.

Comment: Ah sorry you're right, current_user is there globally not as a param. Well actually now that Rails has current_attributes it's not inconceivable the current_user is exposed to the models.

Comment: @JoelBlum I didn't know about current_attributes. The horror!

Comment: haha, it's not so bad if u remember some caveats